# GridView Delete event not picking up gridview data

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is prety simple but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone spot the issue? Delete doesn't work in the gridview. The delete event fires but data is not picked up. Here is the code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAdmins" runat="server" DataKeyField="UserId" Width="200px" DataSourceID="odsAdministratiors" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5" GridLines="None"
  CellPadding="2" RowStyle-CssClass="gridview" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="altbgcolor" 
  OnRowDeleting="gvAdmins_OnDeleting" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleId" HeaderText="RoleId" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />                                                
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />                                                
      <asp:BoundField DataField="altemail" HeaderText="altemail" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
      <asp:TemplateField >
          <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblFnane" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>' /> 
             <asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("lastname")%>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
          <AlternatingItemTemplate>                                                 
            <asp:Label ID="lblFnane" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>' /> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("lastname")%>' />
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true"    />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the ods:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsAdministratiors" runat="server" 
    DeleteMethod="RemoveUsersFromRoles" InsertMethod="AddUserToRolesGroup" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetAdmins" 
    TypeName="ManageAdminRoles" UpdateMethod="AddUserToRolesGroup" >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="altemail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RoleId" DbType="Guid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RoleName" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="altemail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RoleId" DbType="Guid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RoleName" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="altemail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="UserId" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="RoleId" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RoleName" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And the bll methods:

```
private Get_Site_Admins_TableAdapter _Adapter = null;
protected Get_Site_Admins_TableAdapter Adapter
{
    get
    {
        if (_Adapter == null)
            _Adapter = new Get_Site_Admins_TableAdapter();
        return _Adapter;
    }
}

[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
public dsManageAdminRoles.Get_Site_AdminsDataTable GetAdmins()    
{
    try
    {
        return Adapter.GetAdminUsers();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}


[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
public bool RemoveUsersFromRoles(string firstname,string lastname,string Email,string altemail,Guid UserId,Guid RoleId,string RoleName)
{
    int rowsAffected = Adapter.Delete(firstname,lastname,Email,altemail,UserId,RoleId,RoleName);

    try
    {
        return rowsAffected == 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}

[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
public bool AddUserToRolesGroup(string firstname, string lastname, string Email, string altemail, Guid UserId, Guid RoleId, string RoleName)
{
    int rowsAffected = Adapter.Insert(firstname, lastname, Email, altemail, UserId, RoleId, RoleName);

    try
    {
        return rowsAffected == 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Thanks for your hellp.

Risho

Comment: Can you add the deleting event to the datasource and see what the deleteparameters are?

Comment: @Paul: The deleteing event method is called RemoveUsersFromRoles. In debug mode it fires but the variables are null.

Comment: I also made a correction, it used to state ".Update" but it is corrected to Delete: [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]

Answer (score 0):

First thing that is jumping out is that some of your gridview columns are  visible="false", that effectively removes the data binding from that column. Test by changing the visibility to true and see if that helps. You can use style "display:none;" to hide the column but still have it data bound.

Secondly, I don't see any "gvAdmins_OnDeleting" event in your code. Does it exist?

HTH

Dave